# Как сделать кнопку "Возврат в главное меню" в телеграмм боте в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Дан скрипт. Нужно сделать переход на начало скрипта без команды /start, а только нажав на кнопку "В главное меню". Единственное, что у меня получилось сделать, это скопировать данные функции menu и добавить в ответ на кнопку 'В главное меню'. Такую кнопку планирую делать не одну и мне не нравится мой способ "копирования". Предложите идеи, решения данной ситуации

```
import telegram
import telebot
from telebot import types

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def menu(message):
    hello_text = 'Привет1'
    keyboard_1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка1", callback_data="knopka1")
    keyboard_1.add(callback_button_1)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, hello_text, reply_markup=keyboard_1)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'knopka1')
def messendgers(call):
    text = 'Привет2'
    keyboard_2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка2", callback_data='knopka2')
    keyboard_2.add(callback_button_1)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=text, reply_markup=keyboard_2)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'knopka2')
def mainme(call):
   text = 'Завершающий диалог'
   keyboard_3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
   callback_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="В главное меню", callback_data="mainmenu")
   keyboard_3.add(callback_button_1)
   msg = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=text, reply_markup=keyboard_3)
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mainmenu():
    keyboard_1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка1", callback_data="knopka1")
    keyboard_1.add(callback_button_1)
    return keyboard_1


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def menu(message):
    hello_text = 'Привет1'
    keyboard_1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка1", callback_data="knopka1")
    keyboard_1.add(callback_button_1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, hello_text, reply_markup=keyboard_1)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'knopka1':
       text = 'Привет2'
       keyboard_2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
       callback_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка2", callback_data='knopka2')
       keyboard_2.add(callback_button_1)
       bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=text,
                          reply_markup=keyboard_2)

elif call.data == 'knopka2':
    text = 'Завершающий диалог'
    keyboard_3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="В главное меню", callback_data="mainmenu")
    keyboard_3.add(callback_button_1)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=text,
                          reply_markup=keyboard_3)

elif call.data == 'mainmenu':
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                          text='вы вернулись в главное меню', reply_markup=mainmenu())
```

Comment: Спасибо. Оказалось все легко и просто!

Comment: если ответ оказался полезен, отметьте его как решение. спасибо